# django 2.1 rest upload file and get final url

Tags: django

I want to upload file in django rest_framework, my curent code is :

```
class get_contract_events_log(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (BearerTokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    parser_classes = (JSONParser, FormParser, MultiPartParser,)

    def post(self, request, contract_id, format=None):

        screenshot_file       = request.FILES["screenshot_file"]
        mouse_event_count     = request.data["mouse_events_count"]
        keyboard_events_count = request.data["keyboard_events_count"]

        contract = Contract.objects.get(id=contract_id)

        # file_serializer = FileSerializer(data=request.FILES)
        # if file_serializer.is_valid():
        #     file_serializer.save()

        ContractEvent.objects.create(
            #....
            screenshot_filename=screenshot_file,
            screenshot_url="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/Bootstrap-3.1.1-screenshot-jumbotron-example.png",
        )

        return JsonResponse({"message":"log successfully created"}, status=201)
```

Serializer:

```
class FileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta():
    model = ContractEvent
    fields = ('screenshot_file')
```

i my curent code return error :

```
TypeError: The `fields` option must be a list or tuple or "__all__". Got str.
[27/Oct/2018 15:04:25] "POST /contracts/3/events/log HTTP/1.1" 500 18899
```

how i can fix this error ? i need replace screenshot_url with path of uploaded file.

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/
`class Meta` no parentheses. And the post your question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your

```
class FileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta():
    model = ContractEvent
    fields = ('screenshot_file')
```

Correct

```
class FileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta():
    model = ContractEvent
    fields = ('screenshot_file',)
```

add , after 'screenshot_file'